# issue with java generics in an interface

Tags: java, generics

I am implementing an interface that can manage a stack, I have the following code:

```
public interface Stack <E>{
    public int size();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public E top();
    public void push(E item);    //error here
```

and the class that implements this interface has:

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack{
    private E array[];
    private int top=-1;
    public StackArray(int n){
        array=(E[]) Array.newInstance(null, n); ////not quite sure about this
    }
    //more code
    public void push(E item){
        if (top==array.length-1) System.out.println("stack is full");
        else{
            top++;
            array[top]=item;
        }
    }
```

the error that I got is the I am not overriding the push method, I see that both have the same signature, but I am not quite sure.

how can I fix that?

Comment: When you write `implements Stack` you are in fact implementing `Stack<Object>`.

Comment: Be careful about reporting where errors are; it's usually best to just post the error message. The error is **not** in your interface, it's in your implementing class.

Comment: This is why you should always use the `@Override` annotation, your IDE would have inmidiatly informed you what the problem was

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not binding the `E` parameter in `StackArray` to the `E` parameter in `Stack`. Use this declaration:

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack<E>
```